# exists in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

hi I have two tables test1 and test2 like below

```
test1:                                   test2:
folder         analytic                  analytic        status
----------     ----------                ----------      ----------
1              a1                        a1              C
1              a2                        a2              C
1              a3                        a3              N
2              b1                        b1              N
2              b2                        b2              N
2              b3                        b3              N
3              c1                        c1              N
3              c2                        c2              C
3              c3                        c3              N
```

In crystal reports I need to display the analytics which has at least one record with status 'C' in that folder.
That means expected output is

```
analytic
----------
a1
a2
a3
c1
c2
c3
```

how to achieve this... please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Under properties of you field where you are going to show your `analytic`, you need to create a formula condition like this:

```
If {@status} = "C" Then 
True
Else 
False
```

Of course, if it is string.

Comment: that condition will return only a1, a2 and c2

Comment: you need to declare then your analytic names in string and use something like this... If {@status} = "C" and {@analytic} like "mystring(which is C)*" then true. @user1912935